# Iptables troubles

Tags: 14.04, server, firewall, iptables, webmin

I used webwin for iptables management and reset the firewall over webmin (to clear out all the old stuff). I also disabled the feature `Activate at book`.

After that I installed iptables-persistent for restoring my iptables rules after reboot.

The problem is my iptables are empty after reboot.

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What `iptables-persistent` does is it saves the rules to `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` or `/etc/iptables/rules.v6` at install time, and by using `webwin` to remove the rules, it saved a ruleset that had no rules.

Note that `ip6tables` uses `/etc/iptables/rules.v6`, while `iptables` uses `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`.

Add your rules to the `iptables` and `ip6tables` firewalls.  Then, do the following commands on the command line:

```
sudo su -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"
sudo su -c "ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6"
```

Once you reboot or restart, the rules are refreshed from those rules, and you should then have your firewall rules restored.  **Always run those commands if you've edited your firewall rulesets, so you can update what it refreshes from**, as it is not an automatic save process.